# Reversing a null range in Ada

Tags: range, reverse, ada

A piece of automatically-generated Ada code has this line:

```
 for digit in reverse 0 .. 1 loop
      ...
 end loop;
```

which causes gnat ada to emit:

sourcefile.adb:79:41: warning: loop range may be null
sourcefile.adb:79:41: warning: bounds may be wrong way round

What I *want* is for the loop to be executed with digit = 1 then digit = 0 ... but 0..1 **is** a null range, so reversing it still yields a null range, right ?  or is it ?

Answer (score 2):

What Ada compiler and version are you using?

This compiles without warning or error with GNAT GPL 2013:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Reverse_Loop_Test is

begin
   for Digit in reverse 0 .. 1 loop
      Put_Line(Integer'Image(Digit));
   end loop;
end Reverse_Loop_Test;
```

And runs as expected:

```
/home/wintermute/sandbox/reverse_loop_test
 1
 0
[2013-10-02 19:42:24] process terminated successfully (elapsed time: 00.10s)
```

Comment: Marc:  your sample produces the warning of my OP.  "gnat --version" gives:  "GNAT 4.5.4
Copyright 1996-2010, Free Software Foundation, Inc." so it looks like I must update.  But I'm on Gentoo Linux and the version is current, so I'll have to download/build gnat myself. The output is the same as yours, though.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is for the loop to be executed with digit = 1 then digit =
>   0 ... but 0..1 is a null range, so reversing it still yields a null
>   range, right ? or is it ?

`0..1` is not a null range. It is the set of integers {0,1} -- the null range you're thinking of *is* `1..0`, so I would ask if the file you're compiling is really the file you think you're compiling.

Comment: Doh, carelessness on my part, and my apology:  the code snippet is correct and my comment/question is wrong.  See my comment to Marc C's answer below.

Comment: @Michael Small FYI: StackOverflow doesn't display answers in the same order every time, so using words like "below" isn't a good idea.